# Check boxes clicked all

Tags: javascript

I want to select the parent item when any of the child is clicked.  This code is working checked and check.

```
$(function() {
  $(".child").on("click",function() {
      $parent = $(this).prevAll(".parent");
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) $parent.prop("checked",true);
      else {
         var len = $(this).parent().find(".child:checked").length;
         $parent.prop("checked",len>0);
      }    
  });
  $(".parent").on("click",function() {
      $(this).parent().find(".child").prop("checked",this.checked);
  });
});
```

It's working with inputs (See this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/fEWaH/))

```
<input type='checkbox' name='cat' class='parent' value='cat1' />Category 1<br>
<input type='checkbox' name='foo' class='child' value='1' />SubCategory 1<br>
<input type='checkbox' name='foo' class='child' value='1' />SubCategory 2
```

But with  < li >  check is not working (See this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/dR84e/))

```
<input type='checkbox' name='cat' class='parent' value='cat1' />Category 1
<ul>
    <il><input type='checkbox' name='foo' class='child' value='1' />SubCategory 1</il>
    <il><input type='checkbox' name='foo' class='child' value='1' />SubCategory 2</il>
</ul>
```

Comment: you should really display your code, link your fiddles, and explain your problem a little better if you want answers.

Comment: See links for understand the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after looking at your code, i have come up with a solution that i think you're going for.

by using custom attributes, i selected the top level checkbox if one of the child checkboxes is selected. if at least one child level checkbox is checked, the parent level stays checked. otherwise, unchecked. this is probably easier than navigating the DOM and ended up being much less code.

```
$(function() {
  $(".child").change(function() {
      if ($('.child[thisparent=' + $(this).attr('thisparent') + ']:checked').length == 0) {
          $('#' + $(this).attr('thisparent')).prop('checked', false);
      }
      else {
          $('#' + $(this).attr('thisparent')).prop('checked', true);
      }
  });
  $(".parent").change(function() {
      $('input[thisparent="' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
  });
});
```

JSFiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dR84e/8/)

also, your html is invalid. your "il" tags should be "li"

Comment: That's what I want it already, thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Adding the unordered list adds another layer of parent-children.  Edit this line:

```
      $parent = $(this).parent().prevAll(".parent");
```

to this:

```
  $parent = $(this).parent().parent().prevAll(".parent");
```

to correctly point to your intended parent.