# Check box that unchecks all othes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, checkbox

In a form i have a fieldset in which i have a few checkboxes. The last checkbox in the series is going to be labeled "none" and when selected would uncheck all the other options. When one of those options is re-clicked, it should uncheck the 'none' box at that point. Ive been really stuck on how this could be done. here is my html

```
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="checkboxx">
<legend>What Extreme Sports Do You You Play?(check all that apply):</legend>

    <label><input type="checkbox" id="chkSkateboarding" name="chkSkateboarding" 
                  <?php if($Skateboarding) echo ' checked="checked" ';?>
                  value="Skateboarding" tabindex="250"> Skateboarding</label>

<label><input type="checkbox" id="chkPaintball" name="chkPaintball" 
                  <?php if($Paintball) echo ' checked="checked" ';?>
                  value="Paintball" tabindex="260"> Paintball</label>

    <label><input type="checkbox" id="chkSnowboarding" name="chkSnowboarding"
                  <?php if($Paintball) echo ' checked="checked" ';?>
                  value="Snowboarding" tabindex="270"> Snowboarding</label>

    <label><input type="checkbox" id="chkMountainBiking" name="chkMountainBiking"
                  <?php if($MountainBiking) echo ' checked="checked" ';?>
                  value="MountainBiking" tabindex="280"> Mountain Biking</label>

    <label><input type="checkbox" id="chkWakeboarding" name="chkWakeboarding"
                  <?php if($Wakeboarding) echo ' checked="checked" ';?>
                  value="Wakeboarding" tabindex="285"> Wakeboarding</label>

    <label><input type="checkbox" id="chkRockClimbing" name="chkRockClimbing"
                  <?php if($RockClimbing) echo ' checked="checked" ';?>
                  value="RockClimbing" tabindex="290"> Rock Climbing</label>

    <label><input type="checkbox" id="chkNone" name="chkNone"
                  <?php if($None) echo ' checked="checked" ';?>
                  value="None" tabindex="291"> None</label>

</fieldset>
```

Comment: check my answer to this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22566553/check-boxes-clicked-all/22567248#22567248

Comment: So... what you have tried? Or do you expect a fast, free answer to do your job? This is so easy, you should try and learn.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it asks for actual work instead of an answer.

Answer (score 1):

the technique should be simple as the following:

1- We should uncheck the (none) checkbox when any other checkbox is checked.

```
var allOtherCheckboxes = $("input:checkbox:not(#chkNone)");

    // uncheck the (none) checkbox when any other checkbox is selected
    allOtherCheckboxes.change(function(){
    $("#chkNone").prop('checked', false);
    });
```

2- For the (none) checkbox, we should uncheck all other checkboxes.

```
$("#chkNone").change(function(){
        var noneStatus = $(this).prop("checked");
        if(noneStatus === true)
        {
            // remove the checked state from other checkboxes in the page
            allOtherCheckboxes.each(function(el){
                //alert("found");
                $(this).prop('checked', false);
            });
        }
    });
```

I've created this fiddle for you which contains exactly what you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/hakeero/p9bCD/2/

Answer (score 0):

try with this code

```
$("#chkNone").click(function(){
       $( "input[id!='chkNone']" ).prop('checked', false);    
})

$("input[type='checkbox'][id!='chkNone']").click(function(){    
        $( "#chkNone" ).prop('checked', false);    
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gHwgh/

Comment: Thank for the suggestion. I have correct the code

Comment: On click i uncheck all input except Itself. There is id != not equal. Look the fiddle it'work.your comment was right because the if statement was not necessary

Comment: Sorry I was seeing this on a phone - you should however restrict to checkboxes - possibly only name^='chk"